# HorizontalPicker Error in Arabic Language

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I am used below the library

**Horizontal Date Picker**
**implementation 'com.github.jhonnyx2012:horizontal-picker:1.0.6'**

Change Application in Arabic current month not display properly also current date not selected.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The library has a Bug (for RTL) , and its inactive old library .

so I suggest you Change your library

or fix it manually (by downloading library source code and editing it)